# Angular.js: View Transition Animations

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and been following the basic tutorials from their official site but I haven't see any tutorial about animating specifically view transition animations. What I want for example is for my current view to pan to the right to show the next view and hitting the back button pans to the left to reveal the previous view.

Does angular.js supports this out of the box? If it does, what is the proper or recommended way of doing it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[Angular 1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js), released just last night (4/3/2013) supports CSS animation.  Though the documentation and examples are still a little scarce, you'll find a good introduction in [this video presentation](https://plus.google.com/109524702084450613375/posts/dBVBK7w2Aee).

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't provide animations (or much DOM manipulation at all, really) - those would have to be provided by a 3rd party (probably JQuery).

Since you're new to Angular I'd try to write the animations in a non-angular app, get them working, and then read up on Directives to integrate your work into your Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Full Tutorials here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Things has changed a little bit since 1.1.4